# Probabilistic interpretation of linear regression: Why p(y|x) equal to size of the error?

Tags: regression, conditional-probability

I was reading Andrew Ng's CS229 lecture notes (page 12).

The target function y<sup>(i)</sup> can be written as:

y<sup>(i)</sup>=θ<sup>T</sup>x<sup>(i)</sup>+ϵ<sup>(i)</sup>
where,

e<sup>(i)</sup> is the error term that captures unmodeled effects and random noise. Further assume that this noise is distributed as ϵ<sup>(i)</sup>∼N(0,σ2).

In the next step, he equates   *p(Y | x)* to error.

i.e *p(Y | x)* will be a normally-distributed function of the size of the error.

Why is *p(Y | x)* equal to error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put it correctly, he uses $p(\epsilon)$ for writing $p(y|x,\theta)$, because $y=\theta^Tx+\epsilon$, and given $x$ and $\theta$, the only source of randomness is the error term, $\epsilon$. So the RHS is like $a+\epsilon$, where $a$ is a constant. If you shift a normal RV by a constant, by definition you get another normal RV, which makes $y$ a normal RV with mean $a=\theta^Tx$ and the same variance as $\epsilon$, which makes modifying the expression of $p(\epsilon)$ eligible.

Answer (score 0):

I looked into the lecture notes you references and the author points out that
$$
y^{(i)} \, | \, x^{(i)}; \theta \sim \mathcal{N}(\theta^Tx^{(i)}, \sigma^2)
$$
which differs from the density of the errors (having mean 0). The distribution of $y^{(i)}$ does, however share the variance from the distribution of the errors. So $P(y \, |x) \neq P(\epsilon)$.